# Google Cloud Function timeout overrun workaround/alternative

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

My function needs to run once every day. I thought of using `Google Cloud Functions` service along with `Cloud Scheduler`(to automate running it) in that case. The problem is `Cloud Functions` have maximum timeout set as 9 minutes (after that time function is terminated). My function isn't CPU intensive or memory intensive, but needs around `~30 minutes` to execute. Are there any workarounds/alternatives for that case?

Little bit of context: the function I want to run once per day is simple data synchronization between two REST APIs. It takes so long, because of low rate limit of one API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to use [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs) (you only need to add a webserver and to build a standard container. If you share your language, I can provide you examples). Cloud Run has the same behavior as Cloud Function (if you set the [concurrency to 1](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency)) and can handle request up to 60 minutes.

However, be careful of Cloud Scheduler. It is able to handle request only up to 30 minutes, after, it considers the request as failed because of timeout. But, the Cloud Run request can continue correctly up to 60 minutes (after Cloud Run stops the processing). In this case, don't set up [retry policy](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.jobs#RetryConfig) on your Cloud Scheduler and let the Cloud Run continue its processing a full hour. The bad side of that is that you can't use Cloud Scheduler retry policy in case of real error.

Comment: Thank You! Cloud run seems to be the simplest solution to this problem

Answer (score 2):

Because you know the rate-limit of the API, you should be able to calculate how many calls you can do in an 8 minute period. Then after you've made those calls, save your progress to Cloud Firestore in a location monitored by another Cloud Function listening to it using `onCreate`, such as `/_functionsAsyncTasks`. In this Cloud Function, pick up where you left off and do another 8 minutes worth of calls. Repeat until you've worked through all your calls.

Comment: Thank You! This seems to me like better solution than `cloud run`, but I'm too lazy to change implementation that much. Next time I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cloud Functions (2nd gen) now. With longer request workloads up to 60 minutes.

Comment: yes, but only for http triggers in 2nd gen. Eventarc triggers  in 2nd gen also only allow 10 minutes (currently).